# asp.net how to allow only 2 digit after comma

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation, textbox

I have a asp textbox and i want to get amount value of something. I added my validations everything seems ok but after that i realize after comma i should't allow enter mode digits for example;
my text box initial value is 0,00 and user enter a value like this 0,2123 it is possible now but i want to block after 2 digit.I don't want to warning about it i want to users cannot write after 2 digit. They can press on keyboard but shouldn't seem on my text box after two digit

How can i do this?

Comment: Use JavaScript to do this. You will find plenty of examples on the internet on how to do this.